# Why structure assign the size as per as the highest data type?

Tags: c, struct

This is my structure and I want to know the allocated size of my struct object.

```
struct toCheckSize
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct toCheckSize v,w,z;
```

So what's the size of the allocated memory to v,w,z?  As per the compiler, it says the size of v,w,z is 8.

Comment: [An illustrative program.](http://ideone.com/JMGNhP)

Comment: Imagine if it was five bytes and you allocated an array of two of them. How could both integers be aligned?

Answer (score 0):

size of any data type depends on vendors
consider sizeof(int)=4 byte and
sizeof(char)=1 byte

```
    int main()
   {
          struct ex//ex is tag for this structure
         {
            char c;
            int i;

        };//this is the just declaration that ex tag is of the form
         struct ex x,y,z;//memory will be allocated here

       printf("%u  %u  %u\n",x,y,z);
       printf("%u  %u  %u\n",&x,&y,&z);
       printf("%u  %u  %u\n",sizeof(x),sizeof(y),sizeof(z));
       printf("%u  %u  %u\n",sizeof(x.i),sizeof(y.i),sizeof(z.i));
       printf("%u  %u  %u\n",sizeof(x.c),sizeof(y.c),sizeof(z.c));
       return 1;
 }
```

Output

[image: See the output of this program]

Here
for character padding is added to satisfy the allignment constarint which is also vendors dependent

But see the following code:

```
struct record
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float salary;
 };
 struct record student;
```

sizeof(student);====>28bytes.
because there is no need to add padding for  character array

Answer (score -1):

The size of the structure depends on the size of the integer in your system. The size of the integer is **implementation defined**. But given that the size you are seeing for the structure is 8. I would guess that `sizeof(int) == 4`. Then the size is as follows

```
{
  int a,  --> 4 bytes
  char b, --> 1 byte
          --> padding 3 bytes
}
```

Comment: it also depeds on the alignment requirements of the integers.

Answer (score -2):

The padding is used for memory alignment. Modern processors perform better by accessing aligned memory using default packing.
But you can use `struct __attribute__((__packed__)) toCheckSize` to make the structure packed with the exact size.
See also [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)

Comment: 1) This wasn't a GCC question. 2) How do you know his platform has any support for unaligned accesses?